# io:getline(Prompt) in spawned process: Prompt does not display

Tags: erlang

Here's the code:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

test() ->
    register(go, spawn(my, init, []) ).

init() ->
    Reply = io:get_line("enter:"),
    io:format("Reply= ~s~n", [Reply]).
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:test().
true 

3>
```

If I add a `timer:sleep()` here:

```
test() ->
    register(go, spawn(my, init, []) ).

init() ->
    timer:sleep(1000),  %%<<<==========HERE
    Reply = io:get_line("enter:"),
    io:format("Reply= ~s~n", [Reply]).
```

and run the new code in the shell, then after 1 second the shell prompt `3>` in the first example's output suddenly disappears and is replaced by `enter:`:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).    
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:test().
true
enter:
```

And if I enter something, then as expected I see `Reply= xx`.

If I move the `timer:sleep()` to here:

```
test() ->
    register(go, spawn(my, init, []) ),
    timer:sleep(1000).  %%<<======HERE

init() ->
    Reply = io:get_line("enter:"),
    io:format("Reply= ~s~n", [Reply]).
```

and I run the code in the shell, I see:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).    
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:test().
enter:
```

then `enter:` suddently disappears and is replaced by `ok`:

```
1> c(my).    
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:test().
ok    

3>
```

This *does* work as expected:

```
1> Reply = io:get_line("enter: ").
enter: hello
"hello\n"

2> Reply.
"hello\n"

3>
```

Can someone explain what race condition is occurring in the first example?

Comment: What OTP version? I ran first code snippet on 21 and worked !

Comment: @Pouriya, `20.3`.  You can see `Erlang/OTP 20` three times in my output--which is the reason I included it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not exactly race condition. The issue is raised from fact that we have only one std_in stream and only one process in given time can use it.

1) In first code snippet process 'go' takes control on std_in with get_line/1 function first. But after that test/0 function returns to Erlang shell and shell takes control under std_in (Erlang shell is waiting for user input with prompt like ">"). So process 'go' now unlinked from std_in and does not receive any chars from std_in. All input goes to Erlang shell.

2) Second snippet has sleep/1 function in init/1. So situation is opposite. We allow Erlang shell reach waiting for input status and AFTER that execute get_line/1 in 'go' process. So now 'go' process takes control on std_in and receives chars from keyboard. But after 'go' process terminates then Erlang shell restores its state.

3) Third snippet is just 1st but aggravate situation with sleep/1 function.

4) Nothing explain for forth snippet. It works as expected.

5) To illustrate this point of view you can run code below:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

test() ->
    spawn_link(my, init1, []),
    spawn_link(my, init2, []).

init1() ->
    timer:sleep(100),
    init(0, "0").

init2() ->
    timer:sleep(100),
    init(0, "1").

init(N, Title) ->
%    io:format(">>init(~p)~n", [N]),
    Reply = io:get_line(Title ++ "> enter:"),
    io:format("[~s] (e - exit) Reply= ~s", [Title, Reply]),
    case Reply of
      "e\n" -> ok;
      _ -> init(N+1, Title)
    end.
```

The module starts two processes with get_line/1. But only one process can except input from std_in in recent moment:

```
50> my:test().
<0.192.0>
1> enter:w
[1] (e - exit) Reply= w
1> enter:d
[1] (e - exit) Reply= d
1> enter:e
[1] (e - exit) Reply= e
0> enter:dd
[0] (e - exit) Reply= dd
0> enter:e
[0] (e - exit) Reply= e
51>
```

Comment: What about stdout?   Why does erlang allow a process to overwrite another process's stdout?  When that happens it's very confusing because you see output in the shell that neither process output!

Comment: sdtout can except output from multiple processes - it is normal - just do not allow outputs mix out. stdin is different from stdout - stdin (keyboard input) is only one for system (or VM) and has only one destination (get_line function) in given moment. You can test it by adding to code above one more process that outputs some string each second (f.e.).

Comment: Stdout is only one for the system too but sdtout can except output from multiple processes this is difference.

Comment: *sdtout can except output from multiple processes - it is normal - just do not allow outputs mix out.* -- It's not the *mixing* of output that concerns me--it's that one process can overwrite another process's stdout ( see: *the shell prompt 3> in the first example's output suddenly disappears and is replaced by enter:* in my question).  My real code does this in a very perplexing way.  I don't think erlang should let a process overwrite another process's stdout, but I guess it's like two processes writing to a file without synchronizing the file access.

Comment: Please note: processes do not overwrite each other in stdout - they just add new string to end of stdout. But you can see overwriting (symbols disappear as you said) on DISPLAY because string can contain control symbols like \n, \r and so on. That makes symbols on display 'disappear'. In our case it is possible that 'prompt' of get_line/1 clears current line of display before output it. But after we return to Erlang shell "3>" will be here.